# Unable to insert data in sqlite FMDB when app is in background and iphone is in lock mode

Tags: objective-c, background, sqlite, fmdb, ios9.1

I am Unable to insert data in sqlite FMDB when app is in background and iphone is in lock  mode
when i just unlock my iphone then it automatically starts inserting data even when app is in background mode,
please help me, Errors are listed bellow

**Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (14: unable to open database file) eu**

**Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (14: unable to open database file)**

Comment: when device is locked, apple shuts almost everything to save battery and other resources. Why you want to insert data when device is locked ? Can u pls explain the scenario ?

Comment: When the device is locked, full-disk (flash?) encryption is active.  Access to storage which is encrypted will fail.  I don't know the ins-and-outs of this topic, so I don't know if a solution is possible.

Comment: i am saving my current location in  background to get my route at end of the day and it was working till xcode 7 and now it creating problem

Comment: when i execute select query then it works but it creating problem in inserting data

Comment: And it works on simulator

Comment: but it is not working in device